# async.series: memory leak of feature?

Tags: javascript, async.js

I'm studying use `series.js`. I wrote simple example - run `async.series` for 3 functions. By curiosity I created log output before and after callback call. Unexpected for me there is no log messages 'after callback'.

My question is - is it memory leak, and these call are still in stack and waiting to return? Or `async.js` uses special mechanism for cutting functions after callback? I tried to read `async.js` source and found nothing.

Is there any ideas?

Test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>My Page</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/caolan/async/master/lib/async.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var a = function (callback) {
        console.log('a before callback');
        return callback(null);
        console.log('a after callback');
    };
    var b = function (callback) {
        console.log('b before callback');
        return callback(null);
        console.log('b after callback');
    };
    var c = function (callback) {
        console.log('c before callback');
        return callback(null);
        console.log('c after callback');
    };

    var doit = function() {
        console.log('click');
        async.series([a, b, c, a, b, c], function(something) {console.log('async.series happy end: '+something);});
        console.log('series finished');
    };

    $(function() {
        $('#bu').click(doit);           
    });

    console.log('hello');
</script>
</head> 
<body id="bo" class="blue">
<input type="button" id="bu" value="click"><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Log output:

```
hello
event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.
click
a before callback
b before callback
c before callback
a before callback
b before callback
c before callback
async.series happy end: null
series finished
```

Comment: `async` is short for asynchronous, so it makes sense that you see the messages being logged in a different order... it's not a mem-leak AFAIK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no 'after callback' logs because you are returning from the functions before the lines with 'after callback':

```
var c = function (callback) {
        console.log('c before callback');

        // the next line exits this function and nothing after it will execute
        return callback(null);

        // this won't execute because the function has returned.
        console.log('c after callback');
    };
```

Comment: Thank you. It was part of previous experiment, I forgot to remove it... :-(